# build a tree json for jqtree from data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects, jqtree

I am trying to create the tree json for the following data that builds a jqtree

```
var data = [
    {
        "director": "Name1",
        "name": "sub-sub-child1",
        "teamname": "sub-child1",
        "teamManager": "child1"
    },

    {
       "director": "Name1",
       "name": "sub-sub-child2",
       "teamname": "sub-child1",
       "teamManager": "child1"
    },
    {
        "director": "Name1",
        "name": "sub-sub-child2",
        "teamname": "sub-child2",
        "teamManager": "child2"
    },
    {
        "director": "Name2",
        "name": "sub-sub-child1",
        "teamname": "sub-child1",
        "teamManager": "child1"
    },
    {
        "director": "Name2",
        "name": "sub-sub-child2",
        "teamname": "sub-child2",
        "teamManager": "child2"
    },
    {
        "director": "Name3",
        "name": "sub-sub-child1",
        "teamname": "sub-child1",
        "teamManager": "child1"
    },
    {
        "director": "Name3",
        "name": "sub-sub-child2",
        "teamname": "sub-child2",
        "teamManager": "child2"
    }
];

console.log(data);

var aNode = [];
                var aTempNode  = [];
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    //console.log(value);
                    var key = {};
                    if($.inArray(value.director, aTempNode) == -1) {
                        aTempNode.push(value.director);
                        key['label'] = value.director;
                        key['children'] = [{label: value.teamManager, children: [{label: value.teamname, children: [{label: value.name}]}]}];
                        aNode.push(key);
                    } else {
                        //console.log(aNode)
                        if(key['teamname'] == aNode.children) {

                        }
                    }

                });
                console.log(aNode);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elkk/ts9v17xt/4/)

**EDIT2**

The tree should be in this form

```
Name1
 |
 |___child1
 |     |
 |     |___sub-child1
 |     |      |
 |     |      |___sub-sub-child1
 |     |      |___sub-sub-child2
 |     |
 |     |___sub-child2
 |            |
 |            |___sub-sub-child1
 |            |___sub-sub-child2
 |
 |____child2
```

**Edit1**

I'm half way through it. I'm confused how to proceed from here.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elkk/ts9v17xt/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,
You will get what you need in "temp" variable

```js
var temp = [];
$.each(data, function(row, val) {
 var director = $.grep(temp, function(v) {
  return v.label == val.director
 });

 if (director.length) {
  var teamManager = $.grep(director[0].children, function(v) {
   return v.label == val.teamManager
  })
  if (teamManager.length) {
   var teamname = $.grep(teamManager[0].children, function(v) {
    return v.label == val.teamname
   })
   if (teamname.length) {
    var name = $.grep(teamname[0].children, function(v) {
     return v.label == val.name
    })
    if (!name.length) {
     teamname[0].children.push({
      label: val.name,
      children: []
     });
    }
   } else {
    teamManager[0].children.push({
     label: val.teamname,
     children: [{
      label: val.name,
      children: []
     }]
    });
   }

  } else {
   director[0].children.push({
    label: val.teamManager,
    children: [{
     label: val.teamname,
     children: [{
      label: val.name,
      children: []
     }]
    }]
   })
  }
 } else {
  temp.push({
   label: val.director,
   children: [{
    label: val.teamManager,
    children: [{
     label: val.teamname,
     children: [{
      label: val.name,
      children: []
     }]
    }]
   }]
  });
 }

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm, except that it creates empty child nodes though there are no children. http://jsfiddle.net/ts9v17xt/28/